# Page Viewer Web Part on iPad

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, mobile

I'm looking at my sharepoint site pages on my iPad, just to test them out. I switched the view to pc view so it looks the same as being on a computer. I have another website embedded through the page viewer web part on one of my pages. However, I can't see it when I'm using the iPad. Only the title of the web part is displaying. Is there a way to change the safari settings on an iPad to display mixed content?